# how to add custom item to listbox wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add custom items to list box in my program so I have this xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="lb" Background="{x:Null}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Num}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pth}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                        <Button Content="{Binding EnterBtn}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And i have this class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Pth { get; set; }
    public string Num { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EnterBtn { get; set; }
}
```

And in the mainwindow class i have this code:

```
    string path_ = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Documents\folder path", Environment.UserName);
    List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] arr = Directory.GetFiles(path_, ".emi");
        AddToList(arr);

    }
    private void AddToList(string[] a)
    {
        foreach(string s in a)
        {
            string fl;//first line
            string sl; //second line 
            using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                fl = read.ReadLine();
                sl = read.ReadLine();
            }
            itms.Add(new Item() { Num = (itms.Count + 1).ToString(), Name = sl, Pth = fl, EnterBtn = fl + sl });
        }
        lb.ItemsSource = itms;
    }
```

All i want is to read the text file that had (.emi) extension and and update that data to list box.

The problem is that nothing happens and the (.emi) files do exist.

so is there any problem in my code

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `foreach` in `AddToList()`. Run the application and when it stops at the breakpoint, hover the mouse over `a`. What is `a.Length` equal to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`".emi"` will only find files whose exact and complete name is `".emi"`. You want `"*.emi"` -- the `*` means "this part could be any sequence of zero or more characters". [That parameter is a "search pattern"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx), not a file extension.

```
string[] arr = Directory.GetFiles(path_, "*.emi");
```